# keypress event on display button by keyboard click

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

Needs to activation html button

```html
<td> <input name="Eight" type="Button" class="Gray" value="8" onclick='take("8")' /></td>
```

by keyboard event, how can I do this?

What mean key in `keydownFunction(key)`? and `doSomething()` is function instead `take("8")` in `onclick=`? Really dull questions but I'm really don't understand system to call by keyboard events.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
onkeydown="keydownFunction()"
```

If you only want it on a specific key you can do this

```
onkeydown="keydownFunction(key)"
```

Then a function that looks like this:

```
function keyDownFunction(e){
    if(e.which == 10){
       doSomething();
    } else {
       return;
    }
}
```

10 will be whatever your key code is, you can figure out what code you need here
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes